# How to submit text to textarea using python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to send a request to the RNA folding web server (you can find it [here](http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at//cgi-bin/RNAWebSuite/RNAfold.cgi)) using the requests library, but struggling with sending data to the textarea. I have tried to use the usual post method with textarea name and value I want to send in, but it doesn't work.

```
import requests
url = 'http://rna.tbi.univie.ac.at//cgi-bin/RNAWebSuite/RNAfold.cgi'
payload = {'SCREEN' : 'ACUCGAUUCCGAG'}

r = requests.post(url, data = payload)

with open("results.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Is there a way to work with textarea input using requests?

Thank you!

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - doesn't work _how_?

Comment: which python version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code of the webpage it looks like the form requires few more parameters for the POST request to be successfully processed.

Change your payload as below -

```
payload = {
'SCREEN' : 'ACUCGAUUCCGAG',
'PAGE' : '2',                  # hidden input element
'METHOD' : 'p'
}
```

I tested it localy, it works

Comment: That worked for me, thanks. If you don't mind me asking, how do you understand what parameters are required for POST?

Comment: You can inspect the html code of the page and see the <input> elements inside <form>